# The right way to organize controllers with nested resources (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm hoping this question isn't too subjective, but here goes.

For simplicity sake, I've got a User model with many nested resources. For instance, a @user has many @books, @cars, @friends.

In the user's "show" view, I present the user with a dashboard, that shows widgets for all of their things (books, cars, and friends).

My issue now is that the UsersController has to do any/all logic pertaining to books, cars, and friends. And putting logic for Books, etc in the UsersController just feels wrong.

Comment: Mike I'm having the same issue now. Did you find a decent way to organize your controllers without rewriting all the nested routes to point to different controller actions?

Comment: The solution I ended up using was to load each widget (books/cars/friends) via ajax, pointing to that widget's own controller, using nested routes (I.E /users/8/books). This felt a little hacky in the implementation, but very clean from a design sense.

Comment: Was going to post what I did in the comment here but want to show you some code.

Answer (score 1):

In rails you can use nested resources in your routes like so

```
resources :users do
  resources :books
end
```

That would give you something like

```
/users/id_of_user/books
```

Which would hit the index of your books controller, simply check for user_id availability inside your books controller and fetch all books attached to the current user if its there.

Using your controllers and routing this way you can easily spread your logic around to better suited controllers and keep it out of your users controller.

Check out the docs below for more information like snazy helpers for your new nested paths.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I agree that nested resources in the routes is a very clean way of passing data to the controller. But i'll still have the problem where my Users controller is doing a lot of the heavy lifting for books, cars, friends, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Shortly after commenting I found the :[before_filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) on the Rails guide. Using this, you can call actions based on whether the nested resource is found, and the related template. This is what I did, and works well for me!

```
   before_filter :user_resource

      def user_resource
        return unless params[:user_id]
        redirect_to root_url and return unless params[:user_id] == current_user.id.to_s
        action = :"user_#{params[:action]}"
        if self.methods.include? action
          self.send action
          render action
        end
      end
```

and an example of a method it calls

```
  def user_index
    ads = Classified.where(:owner_id => params[:user_id])
    @classifieds = ads
  end
```